# JPA @Version not created in DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, version

My Version column is not getting update/set when i persist an entity using JPA. I am using hibernate jpa.  Does version get auto created or do i have to create it manually?

I have an abstract base class

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract  class AbstractDomainEO {

private Date createdDate;
@Version 
private Integer version;

public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

and sub entity class that extends the abstract class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("GENERIC")
public class ArtData extends AbstractDomainEO  implements DomainObject {
```

---

Update #2....
So I decided to take another simple class with no inheritance just to get the Version to work but have no luck either. My new class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class CarEO implements Car {

private Date createdDate;

@Version 
private Integer version;

public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getCreatedDate() { 
    return this.createdDate; 
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "CAR_ID")
private Integer id;
private String name;
public CarEO() {
    super();
}

@Override
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CAR_ID_SEQ")   
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}
However I still get null for version and createDate(but that is a seperate issue)

**CarEO[createdDate=,version=0,id=3,name=bmw,comments=[]]**

This is the output when i try to create, select delete for this EO object:

[org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL:111 - 
    insert 
    into
        CAR
        (CAR_ID, createdDate, name, version) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        CAR
        (CAR_ID, createdDate, name, version) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?)

[INFO] CarDaoJPASpringTest:64 - **************************
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL:111 - 
    select
        careo0_.CAR_ID as CAR1_1_,
        careo0_.createdDate as createdD2_1_,
        careo0_.name as name1_,
        careo0_.version as version1_ 
    from
        CAR careo0_

Hibernate: 
    select
        careo0_.CAR_ID as CAR1_1_,
        careo0_.createdDate as createdD2_1_,
        careo0_.name as name1_,
        careo0_.version as version1_ 
    from
        CAR careo0_

**CarEO[createdDate=,version=0,id=3,name=bmw,comments=[]]**
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL:111 - 
    delete 
    from
        CAR 
    where
        CAR_ID=? 
        and version=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        CAR 
    where
        CAR_ID=? 
        and version=?

Answer (score 0):

It is miss understanding to use `MappedSuperClass`. `Mapped superclasses` are not queryable, and can’t be used in `EntityManager` or `Query` operations.
`EntityManager` will do `Query` operation for `version` when `EntityManager` perform DB operation to `ArtData`. Now, it is a problem because of your `version` is in `MappedSuperClass`. To avoide this problem, you have to put `version` into `Entity` or `POJO` classes.

Example 1

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract  class AbstractDomainEO {
    private Date createdDate;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("GENERIC")
public class ArtData extends AbstractDomainEO  implements DomainObject {

    @Version 
    private Integer version;

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
@Entity
public abstract class Parent {
    @Version 
    private Integer version;

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass 
public class AbstractDomainEO extends Parent {
    private Date createdDate;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("GENERIC")
public class ArtData extends AbstractDomainEO  implements DomainObject {

}
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqn) for `MappedSuperclass`.

Comment: Example 2 would not work I got this exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.zeltov.eo.AbstractDomainEO

Comment: For example 1 I am still getting a null for the version field : ArtData[version=<null>,id=30,name=art,picture=<null>]

Comment: I am using hibernate "update" property for my hsqldb so not sure if it is not getting mapped correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the initial version.

```
@Version 
private Integer version = 0;
```